# Realmente cual es la diferencia al usar punto y coma?

Tags: javascript

```js
var f = "hola";

(() => {
  
  console.log(f);
  
})();
```

Este código funciona perfectamente, y yo tenía entendido que las `IIFE`, no podían acceder a variables y funciones fuera de esta, entonces no es así?

y he leído sobre anteceder un `;` a la `IIFE`, pero no he entendido mucho su significado, creo que sería algo como colocar el `;` alfinal de una expresión funcional tal que:

```
var a = (function(){

// algo
})();
```

Sería equivalente a:

```
 ;(function a(){

// algo
})();
```

Comment: Según tengo entendido el punto y coma en javascript no es obligatorio. Hay guías de estilo que recomiandan usarla de una forma u otra, o no usar punto y coma salvo en los casos necesarios.

Comment: Podrias leer [aqui](http://variabletecnica.com.ve/2013/03/24/punto-y-coma-en-javascript-es-realmente-necesario/) para informarte mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las IIFE son funciones anónimas cualquiera, es decir una función como cualquier otra pero sin un nombre y si pudes leer variables que estén fuera, pero hay que tener cuidado porque se queda con la referencia de las variables y no con su valor, por ejemplo en el siguiente for se esperaría que imprimiera numeros del 0 al 9 sin embargo solo imprime 10

```js
//Se podría creer que desplegara los numeros del 0 al 9 pero.....
for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
  setTimeout( ()=>(console.log(i) ), 500);
```

En cuanto al punto y coma, no es obligatorio en JavaScript pero es necesario para separar sentencias, tu puedes tener dos lineas de codigo sin punto y como y para ti está claro que son dos instrucciones distintas por estar en líneas separadas, sin embargo, para javascript no, el va interprentando instrucción por instrucción y le da igual si esta en dos líneas o en la misma, por ejemplo:

```
a="hola"
b="mundo"
```

Para javascript sería lo mismo que

```
a="hola"b="mundo"
```

Ahi el interprete no sabe si eso es una suma, multiplicación o que es y te da un error

Tu puedes poner un monton de puntos y coma y simplemente estas separando nada y eso al interprete no le importa

```js
;;;var i=0;;;;console.log(i);;;;
```

Para complementar lo de punto y coma te dejo un ejemplo de al ambigüedad que se da por no usar punto y coma

```js
//Con punto y coma f1 es una funcion anonima
var f1 = (function(n){return n});
(function(){return 8})()
console.log(f1);

//Sin punto y coma f2 es un 8
var f2 = (function(n){return n})
(function(){return 8})()
console.log(f2);
```